# Prettiest way to parse JSON in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, macos

I am trying to parse some JSON from an API, but I have 'trouble' parsing sub-elements of the JSON. My methods of doing that seems like it could be prettier.

I am trying to parse from `http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCUSD/money/ticker_fast?pretty` and I get

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "data": {
        "last_local": {
            "value": "785.00000",
            "value_int": "78500000",
            "display": "$785.00",
            "display_short": "$785.00",
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "last": {
            "value": "785.00000",
            "value_int": "78500000",
            "display": "$785.00",
            "display_short": "$785.00",
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "last_orig": {
            "value": "785.00000",
            "value_int": "78500000",
            "display": "$785.00",
            "display_short": "$785.00",
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "last_all": {
            "value": "785.00000",
            "value_int": "78500000",
            "display": "$785.00",
            "display_short": "$785.00",
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "buy": {
            "value": "785.00000",
            "value_int": "78500000",
            "display": "$785.00",
            "display_short": "$785.00",
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "sell": {
            "value": "785.50000",
            "value_int": "78550000",
            "display": "$785.50",
            "display_short": "$785.50",
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "now": "1386421846023718"
    }
}
```

Now I want to access `value`at `last` at `data`. My way of doing this is nesting a bunch of objectForKey:string -- such as

`[[[[[self getInformationFrom:mtgox] objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"last"] objectForKey:@"value"] floatValue];`

Basically what `getInformationFrom:mtgox` does is return an NSDictionary with NSJSONSerialization.

Is there a better way of getting the value of this JSON data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [dictionary literals](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH7-SW22):

```
[[self getInformationFrom:mtgox][@"data"][@"last"][@"value"] floatValue];
```

Or you could use [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-BAJEAIEE):

```
[[[self getInformationFrom:mtgox] valueForKeyPath:@"data.last.value"] floatValue];
```

Comment: There is also an interface that allows you to specify a dot-separated list, but it's well-concealed in the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, it's valueForKeyPath in the NSKeyValueCoding protocol.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is a communication protocol. The best thing you can do is to parse it into objects first.

For example, create a class `MyPrice` with a method `initWithDictionary:`. This class will read all the `value`, `currency` attributes.

Then create a class `MyData` whose `initWithDictionary:` will read `last_all`, `buy` attributes and delegate the parsing into `-[MyPrice initWithDictionary]`.

Define `readonly` properties on the classes.

Then access data using properties, e.g. `data.lastPrice.value`.

It's more work but it will make your code much prettier because it will work with objects, not with dictionaries.

Comment: +1. This is a great example of more work now leading to less work later. Imagine the other person working on this project. Would they prefer to read `data.lastPrice.value`, or `[[[[[self getInformationFrom:mtgox] objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"last"] objectForKey:@"value"] floatValue];`? Something as important as the cost of something absolutely deserves its own Object. `valueForKeyPath:@"data.last.value"` may be fancy but it is not the same as an Object.

Comment: This is a very important lesson. Creating small data classes saves a huge amount of trouble later on. In particular, it will save you a lot of headache when you realize that you should never manage currency as a float (the small rounding errors will always haunt you). When you realize that you need to manage it as a currency object with an `NSDecimalNumber`, you will be very glad you have a class in place and weren't just handing around floats. (For an example of this, see https://github.com/iosptl/ios6ptl/blob/master/ch17/Money/Money/RNMoney.h)

Comment: @RobNapier I am working for a company that does pricing bussiness. I can only agree. Working with money amounts as integers is another solution but it very often leads to overflows.